# wordpress language change doesn't localize messages

Tags: wordpress

I have the following problem in Wordpress: I can change the language in dashboard and everything in dashboard will be translated to my language. But error messages on my website (404, search not found, etc) continue to stay in english. I tried changing my language back and forth, but to no avail. Has anyone ever come across this problem?

To work around this problem, I changed these error messages in PHP, but I would prefer a correct solution.

Comment: You change only the language of your dashboard and Wordpress system with that. You don't change the language of your theme with that. Did you try using Loco Translate to translate your theme?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I doesn't work as it should. For example. When searching posts by tags, results are shown in correct language. But when searching by post name, the remain in english. I use Sage theme, but this has so far never been an issue before on previous webpages.